# Remove password request after screensaver

Tags: security

How do i change my security settings?

I want to remove, only the password request that shows after the screen saver turns on. 
I'm new with Ubuntu and have not yet figured out were to find the security menu.

Comment: Where is this 'Preferences' option in 11.11 ? Thanks.

Comment: Fred type 'Screen' in the dash to access it. It's slightly different but you click on 'Lock' to toggle the option.

Answer (score 9):

Go into 'Preferences -> Screensaver' and make certain that 'Lock screen when screensaver is active' is unchecked.

[image]